# how to find the code for a specific screen in an android open source project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I think the title is explaining the question enough. let's say I have the code for an open-source application and I'm wondering how some functionality in some screen is implemented in this application.
So I need to find the code for that screen. how can I do that? Finding the screen code base on the class names or packages is not practical in large projects and one can get lost in the source code. is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one perfect way to do it. I usually try one of two approaches:

1. Search for the text which is visible. If the particullar screen shows some static text (meaning, text which is in the `strings.xml` resource file), I do a "search everywhere"* for it in the project. This way I can see, in which fragment / activity this text is called.

*Press Shift + CTRL + F (Shift + Command + F on a Mac) for search everywhere

2. Use the Layout Inspector. Start the app in an emulator or a connected device. In Android Studio, select `Tools` and `Layout Inspector`. The layout inspector will show you a list of all viewable elements including their IDs. Try to do a full search in the project for this ID to see where they are used.
   As an example: In the image below, `tv_welcome_header` is the ID of a `TextView`.

[image: Android Studio layout inspector with a list of all currently visible views]